# Printing x randomIO values from a list of randomIO's

Tags: haskell, random, io, functional-programming

I have been given this snippet of code and am supposed to explain it's non termination and propose a possible fix.

```
randomW =  do randomvalues <- sequence (repeat (randomIO :: IO Float))
              print (take 10 randomvalues)
```

Condition for the fix is to keep generating an infinite list so we may use the take function.

I think the problem stems from the not-so-lazy nature of the sequence function, which tries to reach the end of the list generated by `repeat (randomIO :: IO Float)`, leading to non termination.

I'm also not sure about whether the repeat function is possible on randomIO.

```
test = do random <- repeat (randomIO :: IO Float)
          print random
```

Which yields a type error. Print can't seem to be able to handle an IO Float, which seems to suggest that you can use repeat on type IO Float.

Comment: The problem with the second code snippet is that `repeat randomIO` is of type `[IO Float]`. When doing `repeat randomIO >>= \random -> ...`, you are in fact in list monad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
randomIO :: Random a => IO a
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

=>

```
repeat (randomIO :: IO Float) :: [IO Float]
```

So when you do:

```
random <- repeat (randomIO :: IO Float)
```

You're actually exploiting the list monad here, so `random` has type `IO Float`. Since you're in the list monad, your last statement needs to have type `[a]`, but it has type `IO ()` since it's a call to `print`, hence the type error.

The whole point of sequence is to transform this `[IO a]` into an `IO [a]` that you can perform to obtain a list of random values, and hopefully print this list. Now, when you perform an IO like this, it needs to be performed all at once, unless using `unsafeInterleaveIO`, which is not recommended in this case. So it tries to get that infinite list... and hangs (it might stack overflow at some point, I'm not sure).

To get an infinite list of random values, you don't need all this, just to obtain a random seed, and compute random values purely from the seed.

You should be able to construct an infinite list of random values using these [functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#t%3aRandom):

```
randomIO :: Random a => IO a        -- to provide an IO Int
mkStdGen :: Int -> StdGen           -- to obtain a random generator from that Int
randoms :: RandomGen g => g -> [a]  -- to generate the infinite list
```

Notice that the last two functions are pure. Reading [this thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-July/thread.html#29706) might give you some more ideas.

---

EDIT:

Example of how you should use `mkStdGen`:

```
randomList :: Random a => IO [a]
randomList = do seed <- randomIO
                let gen = mkStdGen seed
                return (randoms gen)
```

I can't test it right now but this should work. You probably want to adapt this to your use case though.

For your other question:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

=>
    map print :: Show a => [a] -> [IO ()]

This probably isn't what you want, right?
If you just want to print a list, no need for `map`, `print` can handle lists.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm currently trying to understand the thread you posted.

I have a question though... When I try:

random2 = do print (take 10 (randoms (mkStdGen 1)))

It gives me type errors, but when I use the same do expression in the Prelude, it somehow does what I want it to do...

Comment: You need to specify the type you expect for the random-generated values, as nothing in the context can help GHC decide what it is. Thus it should be `random2 = do print (take 10 (randoms (mkStdGen 1) :: [Float])) ` if you expect a list of random `Float` values. It works in GHCi because of its type defaulting feature, see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules

Comment: I've managed to do it like this..
random2 = let list = randoms (mkStdGen 1) :: [Float]
          in do print (take 10 list)

But the point of this assignment was to use RandomIO in order to get some side effecting computation in the IO monad.

That being said, since sequence isn't going to cut it. Because it needs to compute fully. Is it possible to use map (print) on this infinite list?

Comment: @Shotor : You're doing it wrong! You should not give a constant seed like `1` to `mkStdGen`, it will always return the exact same list this way! You need to give it a random seed, which is the whole point of `randomIO`. See my edited message for more details.

Comment: You're absolutely right.. I'm using randomIO now to generate an int.. But I still have a type error: random2 = do seed <- randomIO :: IO Int
             list <- randoms (mkStdGen seed) :: [Float]
             print (take 10 list) is my code, which gives errors... I broke down the syntactic sugar as far as I could: random3 = (randomIO :: IO Int) >>= (\x -> print (take 10 (randoms (mkStdGen x) :: [Float] ))) .. To my surprise this version pretty much works as I'd like it to. I really don't see the difference between the 2

Comment: @Shotor : You shouldn't use `list <- randoms ...` but rather `let list = randoms ...` since `randoms` is not monadic.

Comment: random2 = let list x = randoms (mkStdGen x) :: [Float]
          in do seed <- randomIO :: IO Int
                print (take 10 (list seed)) got it :D, Thank you sir, you have been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your first code does not work, is that you're trying to `sequence` an infinite number of `IO` actions. Since this uses strict IO, the program is not allowed to continue before all the actions have been performed, which will take forever.

A simple solution is to `take` the number of actions you need *before* sequencing them, for example:

```
 randomW = do values <- sequence (take 10 $ repeat (randomIO :: IO Float))
              print values
```

This can be written more succinctly using `replicateM` from `Control.Monad`:

```
 randomW = do values <- replicateM 10 (randomIO :: IO Float)
              print values
```

Or, you can use `randoms` to make an infinite list of random numbers based on a single random seed (similar to Ptival's answer):

```
 randomW = do gen <- newStdGen
              let randomValues = randoms gen :: [Float]
              print (take 10 randomValues)
```

Here, we only use a single IO action and the infinite list is generated lazily based on that, so there is no infinite number of side effects to run.

Comment: Just to summarize: The reason this won't work is because when you use randomIO you get an IO Float (in this case), which is more or less a program in it's self, that it print's itself. If we were to use sequence to execute all these commands, it would never terminate because it needs to reach the end of a list.